# Convention for returning from search algorithm - index or iterator

Tags: c++, string, string-matching, calling-convention

Should I return an iterator or an index from a string search algorithm?

In particular, I'd like to conform to C++'s convention. Templated functions such as `std::find` returns an iterator because it has to since some containers are not indexible. More specialized functions such as `std::string::find` returns a `size_t` index.

The check for failure is `== x.end()` for `std::find` and `== std::string::npos` (usually -1) for the specialized version. I think the iterator checking method is more elegant.

Internally, I'll be using indices for performance and convenience reasons regardless of return type.

What are the advantages and disadvantages to each style of returning when I fix the input types (`std::string`)?

Comment: You could return a `std::pair<index,iterator>` if you want...

Comment: @vsoftco that sounds highly unconventional (no offense)

Comment: @self, I agree, however STL is not the best example of a perfectly cohesive library. Hopefully ranges will make it into the standard. And `std::string` is the perfect example, where iterators and indexes are mixed in the interface. If I'd write the function, I would use an iterator pattern, as most of the library is iterator-based. And, if you want to find the actual position, you can then use `std::distance` with the iterator.

Comment: @vsoftco excellent point about `std::string` Most algorithms in stl take iterators, `<container>.begin(), <container>.end()`. I found that pattern consistent .

Comment: @self right, just finished my comment :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be STL-compliant (although even STL is not perfectly designed and `std::string` is the canonical example where indexes and iterators are mixed up), you should use an iterator. Then, can use `std::distance` to find the position in terms of `typename iterator_traits<InputIterator>::difference_type` (i.e., most of the time a `std::size_t`). Of course, this will have an overhead of `O(n)` for non-random access iterators, but it is the most compliant approach.

Hopefully in the future ranges will make it into the standard library
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The convention for `std::string` searching member functions is to return an index of type `size_t` because other member functions, such as `substr`, `insert`, and `erase` take indexes. Some of them provide iterator overloads as well, but not all of them do.

If you plan to use the output of your function with `std::string` functions that take indexes, return an index. If you plan to use the output of your functions with functions that accept iterators, return iterators.